# Error while debugging in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I start debugging in `Visual Studio Code` it gives me error as

> Attribute Program does not exist('Path')

[image]

This is my `launch.json` file code:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\serve",          
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have visited some of links about the same problem but couldn't find any solution? Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since you appear to be on Windows I would try simply reversing your backslashes to a single forward slash / in the program value.

Comment: @Mark I did the same but end up getting the same error.

Comment: How about using serve.js not just serve.  That looks wrong to me.

Comment: @Mark I tried but got same error. I tried `"${workspaceFolder}\\serve.js"`, `${workspaceFolder}/serve` and `${workspaceFolder}/serve.js` but same error.

Comment: Is serve.js in the root of your project file?

Comment: @Mark No it is not. It is not present in the project only. I have searched entire directory but couldn't find one.

Comment: Well, vscode thinks you want to launch a debug session on the file ${workspaceFolder}/serve.js.  Whichever file you want to debug goes where "serve.js" is in the "program" value.  What is the filename you want to run and debug?